# Facebook CodeIgniter - can't log in on first attempt

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-login

I'm using the Facebook PHP integration with CodeIgniter.
I have a problem where I click on the login link, it brings me to the Facebook login, I log in successfully, and when it redirects back to my page, none of the Facebook information has come through. Then if I click the login link again, it immediately logs me in without the need for the Facebook login form. If I were to refresh the page instead of clicking the login link the second time, the Facebook information still wouldn't show.

I feel that it's something to do with the session.

```
$facebook = $this->facebook;
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

*$user* is always 0 until I click the login link for the second time.
This is the login flow:[image]
I feel as if it's failing at the *GET /oath/authorize* phase.

```
public function fb_login() {
    $facebook = $this->facebook;

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('user' => $user));

    var_dump($user);

    $profile = null;
    $logoutUrl = null;
    $loginUrl = null;

    try {
        $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('profile' => $profile));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }

    if ($user) {
        $url = $this->uri->uri_string();
        $url = str_replace('/', '-', $url);
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
            'next' => site_url('[omitted]/fb_logout'.'/'.$url)));
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('logoutUrl' => $logoutUrl));
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'touch'));
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('loginUrl' => $loginUrl));
    }

    $facebook_array = array(
        'user' => $user,
        'profile' => $profile,
        'logoutUrl' => $logoutUrl,
        'loginUrl' => $loginUrl
    );
    return $facebook_array;
}

public function view_events($organiser_type) {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $organiser_type = urldecode($organiser_type);
    $data['organiser_type'] = $organiser_type;

    $data['title'] = $organiser_type.' Events';
    $data['events'] = $this->trinity_impulse_model->get_events_by_type(
            $organiser_type, 
            array('event_start_date', 'event_start_time'),
            array('asc', 'asc'));

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data['events'] as $event) {
        $data['events'][$i]['event_start_date'] = format_timestamp_to('dateFromDB', $event['event_start_date']);
        $data['events'][$i]['event_end_date'] = format_timestamp_to('dateFromDB', $event['event_end_date']);

        $data['events'][$i]['event_start_date'] = humanise_date($data['events'][$i]['event_start_date']);
        $data['events'][$i]['event_end_date'] = humanise_date($data['events'][$i]['event_end_date']);
        $data['events'][$i]['event_start_time'] = format_timestamp_to('shorttime', $event['event_start_time']);
        $data['events'][$i++]['event_end_time'] = format_timestamp_to('shorttime', $event['event_end_time']);
    }        


    $facebook_array = $this->fb_login();

    var_dump($this->session->userdata('user'));
    // Get session values.
    /*$data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');

    $data['profile'] = $this->session->userdata('profile');
    $data['loginUrl'] = $this->session->userdata('loginUrl');

    $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->session->userdata('logoutUrl');
    */
    $data['user'] = $facebook_array['user'];

    $data['profile'] = $facebook_array['profile'];
    $data['loginUrl'] = $facebook_array['loginUrl'];

    $data['logoutUrl'] = $facebook_array['logoutUrl'];


    $this->load->view('[omitted]/view_events', $data);
}
```

**EDIT:** The other pages in my application work as normal. The login displays Facebook data on first attempt. There is nothing different in the other pages. They all use the *fb_login()* function in the same manner.

**EDIT2:** I did *var_dump($facebook)* to see what was different about the variable on the failed login. I found that the *state* is set when I encounter the problem. If it is not set, it logs in with no problem. I still don't know how to resolve that though. Here is the *var_dump()*:

```
["state":protected]=> string(32) "ac816d6fa8fba908b6bd01f3e7f0ec75"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this.
I don't know what the cause of the problem was, but I modified the code and now it works. The offending piece of code was:

```
try {
    $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
```

I wrapped an *if* around it so that it was only called if the *$user* variable was instantiated. Code is like so:

```
if ($user) {
    try {
            $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please send me library files??

Comment: Hi @jack, I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly but if it's to integrate Facebook with CodeIgniter, you can look at this tutorial: http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter